# “你我未来，由此展开。” Is this a real Chinese expression?

Tags: expressions, chengyu, proverb

Is this an authentic Chinese expression? If it is, then why is the only place I see it in use on the Chinese-language version of the US Census website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> “你我未来，由此展开"
>
> "The future of us start here"

It is a slogan (口号).

A slogan is:

- a short and striking or memorable phrase used in advertising.
- a motto associated with a political party or movement or other group.

Slogans come and go, the more memorable ones may be adapted by the public and become part of the daily vocabulary. The one you see here isn't one

[为人民服务](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%BA%E4%BA%BA%E6%B0%91%E6%9C%8D%E5%8A%A1) is an example of a great slogan became a common phrase.

Comment: And it can translate like: To be continue...  lol